# PDF: Character code -> Glyph name -> NSString

Tags: objective-c, pdf, character

In follow up of my previous questions, trying to extract the text from a PDF file using the CGPDF* functions, having a:

```
CGPDFStringRef pdfString
```

I figured out that it can be converted to an array of character codes like this:

```
const unsigned char *characterCodes = CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(pdfString);
```

Now, the text I'm trying to extract is written in one of the 14 type 1 base font's which is not encode in the PDF itself. Therefor, I have parsed the relevant AFM file for that font giving me a mapping from character code to glyph name and it's dimensions like so:

```
C 61 ; WX 600 ; N equal ; B 80 138 520 376 ;
C 63 ; WX 600 ; N question ; B 129 -15 492 572 ;
C 64 ; WX 600 ; N at ; B 77 -15 533 622 ;
C 65 ; WX 600 ; N A ; B 3 0 597 562 ;
C 66 ; WX 600 ; N B ; B 43 0 559 562 ;
```

My question is, knowing the character code, say:*"61"* how do I go from it's glyph name:*"equal"* to a *NSString @"="*.
Especially when that character code is remapped to an other glyph name, say, for instance: *"question"* by the PDF's font encoding option.

Previous questions:
[iOS PDF parsing Type 1 Fonts metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491155/ios-pdf-parsing-type-1-fonts-metrics) and
[iOS PDF to plain text parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465034/ios-pdf-to-plain-text-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but it seems to me that you need to use the [Adobe Glyph Naming convention](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/archives/glyph.html) for this:

> The purpose of the Adobe Glyph Naming convention is to support the
>   computation of a Unicode character string from a sequence of glyphs.
>   This is achieved by specifying a mapping from glyph names to character
>   strings.

The [glyphlist.txt](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/opentype/archives/glyphlist.txt) linked on that page seems to be relevant for your issue.
Sample fragment:

> ...
>  epsilon;03B5
>  epsilontonos;03AD
>  **equal;003D**
>   equalmonospace;FF1D
>  equalsmall;FE66
>  equalsuperior;207C
>   ...

Then all you need to do is [putting those unicode values in your NSString instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839287/nsstring-unicode-display).

**Edit:**
Confirming the information provided above, I found the following explanation on the [PDF Reference Document from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html), *Section 5.9 - Extraction of Text Content*:

> If the font is a simple font that uses one of the predefined encodings
>   MacRomanEncoding, MacExpertEncoding, or WinAnsiEncoding, or that has
>   an encoding whose Differences array includes only character names
>   taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named
>   characters in the Symbol font (see Appendix D):
>
> 1. Map the character code to a character name according to Table D.1 on
>      page 996 and the font’s Differences array.
> 2. Look up the character name in the Adobe Glyph List (see the
>      Bibliography) to obtain the corresponding Unicode value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm pressed for time at the moment on another project. Once I have time to verify your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you yms, I've actually read that outline of the PDF reference as well, it did not stick / make sense to me at that time. Thanks a lot!